# s3cmd obfuscate file names (change to random value) on Amazon S3 side (local original file name)

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, filenames, s3cmd

my `.s3cfg` with GPG encryption passphrase and other security settings. Would you recommend other security hardening?

```
[default]
access_key = $USERNAME
access_token = 
add_encoding_exts = 
add_headers = 
bucket_location = eu-central-1
ca_certs_file = 
cache_file = 
check_ssl_certificate = True
check_ssl_hostname = True
cloudfront_host = cloudfront.amazonaws.com
default_mime_type = binary/octet-stream
delay_updates = False
delete_after = False
delete_after_fetch = False
delete_removed = False
dry_run = False
enable_multipart = True
encoding = UTF-8
encrypt = False
expiry_date = 
expiry_days = 
expiry_prefix = 
follow_symlinks = False
force = False
get_continue = False
gpg_command = /usr/local/bin/gpg
gpg_decrypt = %(gpg_command)s -d --verbose --no-use-agent --batch --yes --passphrase-fd %(passphrase_fd)s -o %(output_file)s %(input_file)s
gpg_encrypt = %(gpg_command)s -c --verbose --no-use-agent --batch --yes --passphrase-fd %(passphrase_fd)s -o %(output_file)s %(input_file)s
gpg_passphrase = $PASSPHRASE
guess_mime_type = True
host_base = s3.amazonaws.com
host_bucket = %(bucket)s.s3.amazonaws.com
human_readable_sizes = False
invalidate_default_index_on_cf = False
invalidate_default_index_root_on_cf = True
invalidate_on_cf = False
kms_key = 
limitrate = 0
list_md5 = False
log_target_prefix = 
long_listing = False
max_delete = -1
mime_type = 
multipart_chunk_size_mb = 15
multipart_max_chunks = 10000
preserve_attrs = True
progress_meter = True
proxy_host = 
proxy_port = 0
put_continue = False
recursive = False
recv_chunk = 65536
reduced_redundancy = False
requester_pays = False
restore_days = 1
secret_key = $PASSWORD
send_chunk = 65536
server_side_encryption = False
signature_v2 = False
simpledb_host = sdb.amazonaws.com
skip_existing = False
socket_timeout = 300
stats = False
stop_on_error = False
storage_class = 
urlencoding_mode = normal
use_https = True
use_mime_magic = True
verbosity = WARNING
website_endpoint = http://%(bucket)s.s3-website-%(location)s.amazonaws.com/
website_error = 
website_index = index.html
```

I use this command to upload/sync my local folder to Amazon S3.

```
s3cmd -e -v put --recursive --dry-run /Users/$USERNAME/Downloads/ s3://dgtrtrtgth777
INFO: Compiling list of local files...
INFO: Running stat() and reading/calculating MD5 values on 15957 files, this may take some time...
INFO: [1000/15957]
INFO: [2000/15957]
INFO: [3000/15957]
INFO: [4000/15957]
INFO: [5000/15957]
INFO: [6000/15957]
INFO: [7000/15957]
INFO: [8000/15957]
INFO: [9000/15957]
INFO: [10000/15957]
INFO: [11000/15957]
INFO: [12000/15957]
INFO: [13000/15957]
INFO: [14000/15957]
INFO: [15000/15957]
```

I tested the encryption with [Transmit GUI S3 Client](https://panic.com/transmit/) and didn't get plain text files.

But I see the original filename. I wish to change the filename to a random value, but have local the original filename (mapping?). How can I do this?

What are downsides doing so if I need to restore the files? I use Amazon S3 only as a backup, in addition to my TimeMachine backup.

Comment: `I wish to change the filename to a random value, but have local the original filename (mapping?)` -- for a backup system I suggest that you don't save the metadata identifying all your files locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "random" names, then it isn't sync.

If your only record on the filenames/mapping is local, it will be impossible to restore your backup in case of a local failure.

If you don't need all versions of your files I'd suggest putting everything in a (possibly encrypted) compressed tarball before uploading it.

Otherwise, you will have to write a small script that lists all files and individually does an `s3cmd put` specifying a random destination, where the mapping is appended to a log file, which should be the first thing you `s3cmd put` to your server. I don't recommend this for something as crucial as storing your backups.

A skeleton showing how this could work:

```
# Save all files in backupX.sh where X is the version number
find /Users/$USERNAME/Downloads/ | awk '{print "s3cmd -e -v put "$0" s3://dgtrshitcrapola/"rand()*1000000}' > backupX.sh

# Upload the mapping file
s3cmd -e -v put backupX.sh s3://dgtrshitcrapola/

# Upload the actual files
sh backupX.sh

# Add cleanup code here
```

However, you will need to handle filename collisions, failed uploads, versioning clashes, ... why not use an existing tool that backs up to S3?